# Firebase - Filtering and Ordering. Noob Question

Tags: firebase

I am trying to filter my data in Firebase and my structure looks like the following:

```
-Lp95KXXJKhKuaA_dbe_:{
     rating: 5,
     date: 12414,
     other properties},
-Lp95RQvvbPxGxkuAyYH:{
     date: 12415,
     rating: 2,
     other properties},
-Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs:{
     rating: 3,
     date: 12416,
     other properties},
...
```

I would like to fetch data that has a rating of 3 or more with a limit of 500 pieces of data. However, each element is pushed onto the database and so the data is in date order ad I would like to preserve this order. Looking through the documentation, if I would like to use `.startAt()`, I would have to order the data by child 'rating'. This means that I will not be getting the last 500 elements with rating 3 or more (which is what I need).

Does anyone know how I would get the last 500 elements with a rating of 3 or more?

Thanks in advance - all help is appreciated.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is to orderbychild on rating and then on the client side reorder it by date and cut everything after 500, but this seems inefficient, especially for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limitToLast(500)` to get the last 500 elements in the database.

From the docs:

> [`limitToLast()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)
>
> Sets the maximum number of items to return from the end of the ordered list of results.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this will solve my problem as it will return them from the list of ordered results, i.e. it wont be the last 500, it will be the 500 with the greatest rating. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: if you do `orderByChild("rating").startAt(3).limitToLast(500)` this should give you a list ordered according to the value of rating, but the ordered list will start from number 3 and above and the list returned will be maximum 500 from the end of the ordered list of results.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the same as getting the last 500 entries with rating 3 or higher. I need the the list returned to be a maximum from the end of the unordered list of results.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, for example: orderByChild("rating").EndtAt(4).limitToLast(1) will return -Lp95RQvvbPxGxkuAyYH, but I am looking for -Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs.

Comment: Can u try `orderbychild("rating").startAt(2).endAr(4).limitToLast(1)` also if u remove `limitToLast` in your code what do u get?

Comment: I haven't actually tested the output for the above. I can try to integrate it into my code. But the the endAt(4) thing was just an example to show my (maybe incorrect) logic that the two results are not equal. Because If I had used the example orderByChild("rating").startAt(3).limitToLast(1) , the result would have accidentally returned the correct element. I think that the same issue will persist with this suggestion as,by using limit to last we are rejecting elements that have a rating greater than 3 that have been pushed recently purely because they have a larger rating than the first 500.

Comment: Actually in ur example u should get `Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs` I thought u already tried it so was shocked with the result, maybe try it and check what u get

Comment: You are correct Peter! I just tried this example and I was given the one with rating 3 (which is what I am looking for). So limitToLast is in reference to the original data, not the ordered data?

Comment: Sorry Peter, I just realised that I made a mistake. Yes I should expect the rating 3 to be returned. I gave a bad example.What I am trying to say is if my data looks like this-Lp95KXXJKhKuaA_dbe_:{
     rating: 5,
     date: 12414,
     other properties},
-Lp95RQvvbPxGxkuAyYH:{
     date: 12415,
     rating: 3,
     other properties},
-Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs:{
     rating: 2,
     date: 12416,
     other properties}, orderbychild("rating").startAt(2).limitToLast(1) will return -Lp95RQvvbPxGxkuAyYH, but I would like it to return -Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs.

Comment: yes it will return `Lp95RQvvbPxGxkuAyYH` but if u use limitToLast(2) it will return this `Lp95RQvvbPxGxkuAyYH` and this `Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs`. I dont think there is a way to only return `Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs`, the only way is to do `orderByChild("rating").equalTo(2)` then you will get only `Lp95s1u4cQ9oHQaFGs` (and any object that contains rating = 2)

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter. This probably isn't the best way of doing it, but I downloaded ALL data with a rating of 3 or more by using orderByChild() and startAt. Then on the client side I converted the object to an array and ordered by date, then sliced the array to get the equivalent of limitToLast and then converted it back to an object again. I am guessing Firebase is not the correct tool for me to be using for this :(.

Comment: probably better to use firestore it contains more filtering